# C++ reference to value, not copy

Tags: c++, reference

I have the line

```
double A =uJoinFeatures1.Values [i];
```

This creates a copy of the double value

```
struct udtJoinFeatures
{
    double Values[17];
};
```

But for speed reasons, I would simply like to reference the value without copying it.
How would I do that, please?

I tried

```
double A =&uJoinFeatures1.Values [i];
```

but that was not possible.

Comment: `double & A = uJoinFeatures1.Values [i];`

Comment: Copying a `double` should be as fast as copying a `double*` and might allow faster access.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier, but you can not use it to assign a value.

Comment: premature optimization? I'm not sure you're going to see any difference in speed, especially if you never write again to the `double A` value, it's a pretty straight forward compiler optimization.

Comment: @Aneri: The reason for a reference in the question was speed, not reference semantics.

Comment: For basic data types and small, simple structs copying by value is often faster. Look up pointer aliasing. To be honest though, unless you are doing something really speed-critical, I doubt you will notice any difference between the two.

Comment: Are you *sure* this is slowing down your code, rather than something else?

Comment: In the first case, the double will be read into a register once. In the second, it will (often) be read into a register every time you access it. If you do it more than once, it will be slower.

Answer (score 5):

You declare `A` as a reference to a `double`:

```
double& A = ...;
```

In this case though, it really is not going to be any speed increase. On a 64-bit machine both a `double` and a pointer (which references really are) are both 64 bits, the same amount to copy. And because references are actually just another name for pointers, you have the indirection when you access the reference which probably adds *more* instructions than using just a `double`.

Not that it's going to be measurable anyway, unless you do this for many millions of items in a tight loop.

Comment: @tmighty Then `const double& A = ...;` I also updated my answer, and I suggest you re-read it. To summarize: You're not going to get a speed up (not nothing that is measurable anyway), and maybe it's going to get *worse*.

Comment: Yes, I read that like a vacuum cleaner :-) I was just unsure why you did not say "const", and I was wondering if I missed something else.

Comment: @tmighty Declare `const` if you don't want to modify it. Works just as well with the non-reference version, and in both cases the compiler will most likely make some nice optimizations to make the "speed" issue even more moot.

Comment: No doubt, references and pointers are similar to one another, but I wouldn't say one is _just another name for the other_.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah sorry, my fault. I did not state that I don't want to edit it... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For speed reasons especially, by all means COPY!

Indirect access is likely to cost more than copying few bytes, especially since it makes it harder for the compiler to keep the value in registers (it would have to optimize the reference away first; references can only point to memory).

In any case it is definitely a premature optimization. After you've made sure all your algorithms have optimal complexity, minimized allocations, work duplications and all other algorithmic problems, you should ensure that the inner loops are inlined and than you'll find that the compiler will do the best possible thing with the normal copy variant anyway.